# Using vaultr in R to pull a password from Hashicorp Vault

Tags: r, password-protection, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to pull a database password from a Hashicorp vault using the vaultr package in R. I use this password in my R code to pull data from a SQL server.

The vault admin has provided a URL and token for me to use within my R script to pull my database password.

As per the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vaultr/vignettes/packages.html) I have modified my project environment variables (`usethis::edit_r_environ("project")`) to include the vault address, the token and the auth method.

I then restart my R session and verify they are set as expected:

```
Sys.getenv(c("VAULT_ADDR", "VAULT_TOKEN", "VAULTR_AUTH_METHOD"))

VAULT_ADDR = https://mycompany.com/v1/Dept/APP/INFRASTRUCTURE/PROD/division/data/rx?version=1
VAULT_TOKEN = someRandomTokenHere
VAULTR_AUTH_METHOD = token
```

I have then tried to access the vault by creating a client:

```
vault <- vaultr::vault_client(login = TRUE, quiet = FALSE)
```

but when I run this step I get the following error:

```
Verifying token
Error: Token login failed with error: no data provided
```

I have tried searching for a solution to this but am finding nothing hence the S.O. question. If you have any pointers I would be grateful for advice.

Comment: I haven't used vaultr, but have you tried leaving off the `login = TRUE` bit, and then running an explicit `client$login(method = "token",  token = token)`?

Comment: That comes from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vaultr/vaultr.pdf